# Django 2.0 use ORM in Python script in parent directory of django folder

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following structure for my project:

```
.
├── py_file_i_want_to_use_core_models_in.py
├── web_app
    ├── core
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── core_settings.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── static
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── web_app
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    └── manage.py
```

I want to access some models define in `web_app/core/models.py` from inside the python script `py_file_i_want_to_use_core_models_in.py` but I cant seem to get the code I am finding to work:

Here is what I am trying:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web_app.web_app.settings")

import django
django.setup()
```

But these imports give me the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'`

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You have to specify `"core"` in your  `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Comment: @dmitryro I have `core.apps.CoreConfig,` in `web_app/settings.py`
`

Comment: Then in the below answer your settings in `wsgi.py` and `manage.py` should be 
`web_app.settings`, unless you follow the described structure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory named `settings` and place your original settings from file `core_settings.py` there - even better, create `development_settings.py` and `default_settings.py` out of it for development, production, staging and so on , so your hierarchy will be like

```
 +core
 |
 +web_app+
 |       |
 |       +urls.py
 |       |
 |       +wsgi.py
 |
 +settings+
 |        |
 |        +settings.py
 |        |
 |        +default_settings.py
 |        |
 |        +development_settings.py
 + manage.py
```

Then, your web_app/wsgi.py should be like:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Your manage.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Then your settings/settings.py

```
from .development_settings import *
```

Or

```
try:
    from development_settings import *
except ImportError:
    from default_settings import *
```

I'm assuming Python 3 and Django 2.0

That should give you a working environment when you use your `manage.py`, provided all the apps are in `INSTALLED_APPS` of your settings files.
Your original location of `settings.py` - in your case `core_settings.py` - is not where it has to be - and if placed there, then `wsgi.py` and `manage.py` need to be updated accordingly, but as a matter of good practice, it's good to keep settings out of a particular application.